# If $\frac{d^2v}{dx^2}=a^{2}v$ and $v=v_0$ at $x=0$ and $v=0$ at $x=l$, then find the value of $v$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, unbounded-operators

Using $D$-Operator method, in the answer, it is given that $v=v_0\frac{\sinh a(l-x)}{\sinh l}$. But after solving it, i got $v_0=c_1+c_2$ and $c_1e^{al}+c_2e^{-al}$ after solving $m^{2}=a^{2}\implies m=\pm a$. But even after considering all the factors and solving these equations, i am still not getting the answer as given in the book. Please help
$$c_1=\frac{v_0}{1-e^{2al}}
\\
c_2=\frac{-v_0e^{2al}}{1-e^{2al}}$$

Comment: Could you please edit your question by using MathJax everywhere not just in a selective manner? You can use for example v_0 to get $v_0$ or \sinh to get $\sinh$.

Comment: $v0=c1+c2$ and $c1e^{al}+c2e^{-al}=0$ are correct. Pleass show how you  got stuck after this. What are the values of $c_1$ and $c_2$ you got?

Comment: @Gary i have edited please check and if possible please answer my question

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy ,I have written the values of $c_1$ and $c_2$ . Please check and if possible please answer my question

Comment: Now if you cancel $e^{al}$ in the fractions and recognize that $e^{al}-e^{-al}=2\sinh(al)$, you get, almost, to the claimed formula (that is missing an $a$ in the denominator).

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann Hello sir, Can you Please answer by writing the steps after i found $c_1$ and $c_2$, so that i can understand clearly. Please sir

Answer (score 1):

With the symmetric exponents it is sometimes helpful to combine them from the start into the odd and even parts of the exponential, as per
$$
e^{\pm ax}=\cosh(ax)\pm\sinh(ax).
$$
The only term with a root on the right side is the hyperbolic sine and has it at $x=0$, which is not helpful with the boundary conditions. However, adding a constant in the exponent only changes the coefficients, so that one can write the general solution also as
$$
v(x)=c_1\cosh(a(x-l))+c_2\sinh(a(x-l)).
$$
From the second boundary condition it now directly follows that $c_1=0$ and inserted into the first
$$
v_0=v(0)=c_2\sinh(-al)=-c_2\sinh(al).
$$

Comment: But how did you write v(x)=$c_1cosh(a(x-l))$ + $c_2sinh(a(x-l))$, i did not understood that part ?

Comment: Because the equation is autonomous, with $v(x)$ you also get $v(x-l)$ as a solution.